# Publish local branch on remote but not merge it into the remote branch it tracks

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I have gone through a huge refactoring effort and would like to push my local `git` branch (call it `local_b`) into a temporary remote branch which my CM can deploy in a dedicated environment for the QA to test.  However, before some testing is done, due to the risks involved, I would rather not merge it into the ultimate target remote branch (call it `official_b`) that my local branch tracks, i.e. from which I fetch other developers' changes.

Is it possible for me to:

1. Promote `local_b` to the remote (call that new remote branch `test_b`)
2. Keep the local branch as tracking the `official_b` for synchronizing with incoming merged changes from other developers
3. Push all changes from `local_b` (merged changes from `official_b` + my local changes) into `test_b`

all at the same time using some git gimmick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I do not understand wrong, you want to push your `local_b` branch and update it with the changes done in `official_b`.

For pushing your local branch to the remote:

```
git push origin local_b:test_b
```

And for updating your branch:

```
git checkout local_b
git rebase official_b
# ... Fix possible conflicts
git push origin local_b:test_b
```

Comment: while tracking `local_b` to `official_b` and publishing `local_b` to `test_b`

Comment: @amphibient The branches `local_b` and `official_b` are different. You can not track it, but what is wrong in updating the changes from the official branch to your `local_b`, if you want `local_b` to have its changes?

Comment: yes, `local_b` = `official_b` + `my changes`.  i guess you are right in that i can fetch from `official_b` into `local_b` but push from `local_b` into `test_b`

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not:

```
# Promote local_b to the remote (call that new remote branch test_b)
git push origin local_b:test_b

# Push all changes from local_b (official_b + my local changes) into test_b
git push origin local_b:test_b  # so yes, same command as earlier...
```